# Bluetooth devices missing Manufacturer name and product name

Tags: bluetooth, nixos, blueman

Using blueman on NixOS to pair bluetooth device (headphones) and I am only getting a list of MAC addresses without names. I was expecting to see Apple EarPods, for example, but didn't see any names.

```
~ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 18:56:80:00:AC:92 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 70:83:4A:D3:D1:60 70-83-4A-D3-D1-60
...
```

When I check `journalctl -eu bluetooth`:

```
Oct 31 09:15:21 nixos bluetoothd[27637]: RFCOMM server failed for ...: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

I assume that is related to opening the `blueman-applet` while it was already running, rather than the main issue.

My NixOS config includes:

```
  services.dbus.packages = [ pkgs.blueman ];
  services.blueman.enable = true;
```

How to lookup bluetooth device names, or at least start debugging?